# how to enqueue style from get_option in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

In WordPress admin i've created an option to select custome stylesheet for frontend. i have to enqueue_style from admin option. i'm tring something like below...

```
$options = get_option( 'admin_theme_option' ); 
function theme_script_enqueue(){

if($options){

wp_enqueue_style('customestyle', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/'.$options['themecss'],array(),'1.0.0','all');
}else{

wp_enqueue_style('customestyle', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/default.css',array(),'1.0.0','all');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','theme_script_enqueue');
```

but it is not working. please let me know if any other method is there.

Comment: You need to go learn some PHP basics - in this case, about variable scope. http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php There is no $options available inside your function. Also, go and configure your PHP and/or WordPress to show you proper error messages in such cases.

Comment: can you paste the option field from your framework too?

Comment: @Gazi :-  [themecss] => theme_style1.css

Comment: @Gazi - i'm adding records in wp_options table to the admin side. and i have to retrieve the value in functions.php inorder to enqueue stylesheet which is inserted in the wp_options table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function theme_script_enqueue(){
$options = get_option( 'admin_theme_option' ); 
if($options != "") {
$mystyle = 'custom_style'; //css file name
} else { 
$mystyle =  'default_style'; // your default css file name
}
wp_enqueue_style('customestyle', get_bloginfo( 'template_url' ) . '/'.$mystyle.'.css'); 
}
add_action('wp_head','theme_script_enqueue');
```

you must get `$options = get_option( 'admin_theme_option' );`  into the function

Comment: thanks I changed my answer again there to wp_head instead if you want you can use wp_footer to move to the footer